# Alternative notation for Kleene star

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, formal-languages

I am writing a paper which use two different operations on sets of works $X$, both of which I want to denote by a star, $X^{\ast}$. One of these operations is the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), and for whatever reason I would like to keep the other operation as a star and change my notation for the Kleene star operation. Therefore, I was wondering if there is another, (relatively-commonly-used) notation for the Kleene star?

(This is not my area. I have read about a bit but not found any other notation. Also, I do realise that changing the notation of something with "star" in its name is...odd...)

Comment: Nobody uses any other notation for Kleene star.

Comment: $X^\ast$ = Kleene star, ${}^\ast\! X$ = user111368 star.

Comment: There is the $!A$ construction of linear logic which is arguably a form of Kleene's star, but people not familiar with LL would probably find this very confusing. Instead, I would rather suggest something like $X\star$ or $X\bullet$: a mere difference between two types of star is probably too confusion, but combined with a superscript / non-superscript difference, I think it can do the trick.

Comment: The notation $X^{<\omega}$ is often used in set theory to refer to the set of finite sequences from a set $X$, and this is basically the same thing as the Kleene star, if one views words on $X$ as finite sequences from $X$. This notation is used more generally with $X^\kappa$, $X^{<\kappa}$ and so on, for arbitrary ordinals. But I don't recommend using this notation just in order to free up $X^*$ for another use, since the $X^*$ notation is extremely common and people would likely misunderstand.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Is the Kleene plus a "thing"? (Wikipedia mentions it, but if I used it would you know what I meant? Using it would be a potential fix.)

Comment: $X^+$ excludes the empty string.

Comment: Although it is better to use the common notation for any concept in the papers, it is not a rule, and you may define your own notation for any concept at the beginning of the paper, and use it throughout the paper. By the way, I see that you have a couple of suggestions here as well.

Comment: Let me add that in any context in which you are using $X^+$ notation or other regular expression notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), then it would be confusing to use $X^*$ to mean anything other than the Kleene star.

Comment: You will definitely confuse language theorist with any other use of * in the paper. I got in trouble once because I accidentally used Kleene star and the notation $\mathbb Q^*=\mathbb Q-\{0\}$ in the same paper.

Comment: I'd advise against using $X^*$ with a strange meaning and $X^+$ as Joel says.

Comment: This may depend on your audience. If you are writing for operator algebra people and star is adjoint and no formal language people will read your paper you can probably use plus and just have a remark that + allows no empty string and star usually means something else in formal language theory.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The OP apparently intends to apply the Kleene star operation to a set $X$ of words (I assume "works" is a typo for "words"), in which case it would not be the set $X^{<\omega}$ of finite sequences of elements of $X$ but rather the set of concatenations of such sequences.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think that you are right.

Answer (score 1):

$X^*$ simply is the submonoid generated by $X$ of the free monoid of words over some alphabet, hence you could use the notation $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?